# LDAP query for deleted users

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

The normal way to query a directory for users is `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))`. The normal way to query for deleted objects is to add `(isDeleted=TRUE)`.

However, the `objectCategory` attribute does not exist on tombstone objects, so a query for `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(isDeleted=TRUE))` will get you nothing.

If you remove the `(objectCategory=person)` part, you'll get computers too, as they inherit from user.

Is it possible to retrieve only deleted users?

If not, is it possible to tell from the returned tombstone object if it's a user or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try an LDAP filter like:

```
(&(isDeleted=TRUE)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=512))
```

This should retrieve most deleted user type entries.

Comment: Do you have any example on PHP or Python?, it doesn't work only on the filter query on linux

Answer (score 1):

python3 code

```py
import ldap
from ldap.controls.simple import ValueLessRequestControl
...
base = 
scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
filterstr = '(&(objectClass=user)(isDeleted=TRUE))'
attrlist = 
result_set = []
ct = ldap.controls.simple.ValueLessRequestControl('1.2.840.113556.1.4.417', True)
result_id = l.search_ext(base, scope, filterstr, attrlist, serverctrls=[ct, ])
for i in range(0, 100):
    result_type, result_data = l.result(result_id, 0)
    if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
        result_set.append(result_data)
    else:
        break
...
```

---